# On what basis do countries repay international loans?

Tags: loans, currency, international, sovereign-default

Most countries have their own sovereign currency. Essentially they can print their currency. So how do countries repay their loans? And a similar question would arise while granting a loan to another country. On what repayment terms are loans granted by one country to another country?

The premise of asking this question is... Can US (for example), say just print money and revive any economy? In fact, it did do in 2009 printed out trillion dollars declared to be used for the health sector... And now it has done again added multiple trillion dollars for infrastructure... And other countries can also do... just that it 'may' lead to a devaluation of their currency. But it doesn't matter for the economy provided it continues to export... The case of zimbabwe was weird coz it was not a self-sufficient economy in the first place...

And US has also removed the gold standard in 1971. So on what basis is currency printed by US?

Comment: International loans are usually done in either the currency of the lending country or a stable 'reserve' currency like the US dollar or Euro.

Answer (score 2):

There are only a small number of countries that have the privilege of borrowing money in a currency that they control. Chief among them are the US, Japan and the UK. Most other countries either don’t control their own currencies (e.g. the Eurozone countries) or have to borrow money in an international reserve currency rather than their own currency. Lenders won’t lend money to countries in their own currencies unless they have a very long track record of managing those currencies responsibly, for the very reasons that you cite.